# EF Core ExecuteSqlRaw gives "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first"

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

First, I know there are a lot of past questions about the error in the title. However, none of them seem to be from calling `dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw` and getting a result.

I'm trying to call an old SQL Server function using Entity Framework Core. `dbContext` is passed into my repository by dependency injection. The database function takes in a couple of integers and returns a string:

```
public static string GetCitation(int documentId, int documentTypeId, MyDbContext dbContext)
{
    var result = new SqlParameter("@result", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    {
        Size = 2000,
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    };
    var documentIdParam = new SqlParameter("@documentId", documentId);
    var documentTypeIdParam = new SqlParameter("@documentTypeId", documentTypeId);
    dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("set @result = dbo.fnGetCitation(@documentId, @documentTypeId);", documentIdParam, documentTypeIdParam, result);
    return result.Value.ToString();
}
```

I know this is a bit unorthodox, but it's an old database function which is fairly complex, so I don't want to convert it to EF Linq syntax at the moment.

I also know that the EF Core docs recommend mapping user-defined database functions to the db context's model builder with `modelBuilder.HasDbFunction` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping). I tried implementing it this way, and it worked. However, I use db scaffolding to dynamically generate the db context file. So any time in the future I want to scaffold more tables/columns, the database function mapping will be wiped. As far as I know, there's no way to include database function mappings using the db scaffold command to prevent this from happening.

Any help resolving this error I get:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: I used your code to execute a (not too simple) function. It works with and w/o enabling MultipleActiveResultSets (MARS). I wonder how the function itself can affect this, hard to imagine. Is anything else happening through the same connection before or after this code?

Comment: @GertArnold thanks for trying it out. Before calling this method I use the same `dbContext` in the repository method to get a list of entities (using the regular linq select syntax with `ToList()` at the end). I tried passing in a separate db context to the class where I call the above code using dependency injection, but the same error occurred so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: @GertArnold I just figured it out. Missed something silly. I'll write an answer. Sorry and thank you!

Comment: Happens to me all the time, just by asking the question your brain starts ticking :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was calling `GetCitation` inside a DbSet Select statement.

As I mentioned in my question, I initially tried calling the database function as the EF Core docs suggest: register the function with the model builder inside the db context class. This is what I had in MyDbContext.cs:

```
public string GetCitation(int libraryDocumentId, int libraryTypeId)
    => throw new NotImplementedException();

// Farther down inside `OnModelCreating`
modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(typeof(MyDbContext).GetMethod(nameof(GetCitation), new[] { typeof(int), typeof(int) }))
    .HasName("fnGetCitation");
```

Then in my repository method I called this in a DbSet Select statement:

```
List<Documents> documents = dbContext.Documents
    .Where(d => d.DocumentCategory == category)
    .Select(s => Document
    {
        Citation = dbContext.GetCitation(documentId, documentTypeId)
    }).ToList();
```

This was correct and it was working. But I couldn't use this because I dynamically generate MyDbContext.cs using db scaffolding. So I used the approach I mentioned in the question, except it can't be called inside the Select statement as I did in the code block above.

I modified the code to call `GetCitation` for each document after the documents were returned, but I actually had two Select blocks and only removed it from one which is why I was still getting an error. After removing it from the second one it worked.